# samsung scx4729 scanner not working with ubuntu 18.04 (printer OK)

Tags: scanner, samsung

My printer/scanner Samsung Scx 4729 works fine with all my computers under Ubuntu 16.04.
However, after installing it in my new laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, the scanner doesn't work (in both usb connection and wireless).

> Laptop: Dell inspiron 15 3000
>   System: Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ scanimage -L     
device `xerox_mfp:libusb:001:006' is a Samsung SCX-472x Series multi-function peripheral

$sudo sane-find-scanner    
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3453 [SCX-472x Series]) at libusb:001:006
```

I also check that the file */etc/udev/rules.d/59-smfp_samsung.rules* does contain the entry for my printer

```
ATTRS{idProduct}=="3453", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

I use the driver download from samsung website *uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz*.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank you
Andy

Comment: Same problem here, Dell Inspiron AiO, Samsung M2070w